# SerializeObject adds unicode c#

Tags: c#, json, unicode, entity

I have a WCF service that returns database tables in JSON format. SeralizeObject adds unicode to my httpresponse, how can i remove this?

Code:

```
using (var db = new newTestDBContext())
        {
          var query = from b in db.Roads
                       orderby b.roadID
                     select b;
          Road rr = query.First();
          var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects };
          return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rr, Formatting.Indented, serializerSettings);
```

Reponse:

```
"{\u000d\u000a  \"$id\": \"1\",\u000d\u000a  \"roadparts\": [\u000d\u000a    {\u000d\u000a      \"$id\": \"2\",\u000d\u000a      \"Road\": {\u000d\u000a
```

Comment: I wonder if this is actually because you are returning a string via json, where that string happens to also *contain* json, so it is having to encode the newlines etc that json.net added because of `Formatting.Indented`. Frankly, the first thing I would do would be: don't add `Formatting.Indented`. The second thing I would do is check whether it is being converted to json too early (or: twice).

Comment: My WebGet returns json: ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, my function GetData returns a JSON aswell from SerializeObject. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json

That will JSON encode the return value of the annotated method. If the return value is already  a JSON string, then you are JSON encoding twice.. first the `Road` object and then the JSON string resulting from the former.

So just return the `Road` object and let the `WebMessageFormat.json` handle the json encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Formatting.Indented in your json call. That should fix it.